# How to combine selected out cells into a list?

Tags: front-end, cells

I have a loop that was printing out results, and now I'm left with many cells in different sections and I need to combine them (the values in them) into a list I can work with. For example, applied to 
[image]

it would give me

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, ..., 4000}
```

**Clarifications:**

- The results I want to collect are cells generated by Print[].
- I do not want to have to recompute the cells that were outputted.

Comment: `Sow`/`Reap`?  Or are you trying to avoid recomputing the printed values?

Comment: Are the results you want to collect are generated by `Print`?

Comment: @kuba just saw these, sorry! @2012rcampion yes, would be very costly to recompute them, @kguler yes they are generated by `Print`

Comment: @M.R. Please edit your question to reflect that and I shall reopen this.

Comment: @M.R. Thanks for the edit. Reopen vote casted.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say those cells are selected and the parent notebook is `nb`, you can do something like:

```
RawBoxes /@ NotebookRead[SelectedCells@nb][[;; , 1, 1]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps something like:

```
Lastt@Reap[For[j = 1, j <= 10, j++,Print[Sow@j]]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for something different, and given you seem to want the values of the print cells,

```
tmp = NotebookGet[EvaluationNotebook[]];
Cases[tmp, Cell[BoxData[p_], "Print", ___] :> p, \[Infinity]]
```

If you have other print cells that you do not want in the list, i.e. non integers, then you can obviously add some tests.

Answer (score 1):

If the results you wish to collect are all generated by `Print`, then you can use @Kuba's line in combination with `NotebookFind`:

```
NotebookFind[EvaluationNotebook[], "Print", All, CellStyle]; 
printresults = RawBoxes /@ NotebookRead[SelectedCells[]][[;; , 1, 1]];
```